# Enforcing .destroy() in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am attempting to do a DELETE request for a model view in Backbone. However, when the link is clicked, Backbone is doing a GET request. How can I force the model view to destroy the model instead of get it?

**Jade/HTML**

```
script(type="text/template", id="allContactsTemplate").
  <td><%= first_name %></td>
  <td><%= last_name %></td>
  <td><%= email %></td>
  <td><%= description %></td>
  <td><a href="contacts/<%= _id %>" class="delete">Delete</a></td>
```

**Backbone JS**

```
// Single Contact View
App.Views.Contact = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',

  template: template('allContactsTemplate'),

  events: {
    'click .delete': 'deleteContact'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.model.on( 'destroy', this.unrender, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
    this.$el.html( template );
    return this;
  },

  deleteContact: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
  },

  unrender: function() {
    this.remove();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not cancelling the `<a>`'s default click action anywhere so clicking your `.delete` does two things:

1. Calls `this.model.destroy()` which should trigger a DELETE request.
2. Triggers the usual `<a>` behavior which would be a GET `contacts/some_id` request.

Presumably the GET will take over the browser before the AJAX DELETE gets a chance to do anything. You should cancel the `<a>`'s default action in the usual ways:

```
deleteContact: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.model.destroy();
}
```

or:

```
deleteContact: function() {
    this.model.destroy();
    return false;
}
```

You probably don't even need an `href` on that `<a>` (unless your CSS cares).

Comment: Thanks — I wasn't setting `idAttribute: "_id"` in the contact model, so the parameters were not matching and thus causing this behavior.